# Qt: c++: how to fill QComboBox using QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox

I am trying to add items to `QComboBox` using `insertItems` function as follow:

```
QStringList sequence_len = (QStringList()
<< QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "1", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
<< QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "2", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
<< QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "3", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
<< QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "4", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
<< QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "5", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8)
);

ui->QComboBox->insertItem(0, &sequence_len);
```

but is not working, giving me the following error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QComboBox::insertItem(int, QStringList*)'
```

Actually, when I write `ui->QComboBox->insertItem(` in my class to see the Qt-Creator's suggestions, the option:`(int index, const QStringList & list)` doesn't appear to be exist. So, at first, I thought it is because my Qt-Creator doesn't support this function. However, surprisingly, when filling the `QComboBox` directly from the "Design" tab in Qt-Creator after creating the `QComboBox` widget, the same function is being used by `ui_mainwindow.h`.

why is this happening and is there is a way to add this function to my class as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [addItems](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#addItems) or [insertItems](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#insertItems) member function of QComboBox. //notice there is an **s** in the end for the functions that takes a QStringList argument: it's add/insert Item**s**

LE: don't pass the address of your QStringList, the function takes a reference to a QStringList object, not a pointer, use: `ui->QComboBox->insertItems(0, sequence_len); //no & before sequence_len`

Complete example of filling QComboBox (considering that `tr()` is properly setup):

```
QStringList sequence_len = QStringList() << tr("1") << tr("2") << tr("3") << tr("4") << tr("5");
//add items:
ui->QComboBox->addItems(sequence_len);
//insert items into the position you need
//ui->QComboBox->insertItems(0, sequence_len);
```

Comment: Thanks. Removing the pointer and replace insertItem by addItem make it work.

Comment: insertItems should work too, it was my hurry read that made me point to addItems - and than i saw the error you have...

LE: error again - it also has insertItem_s_ (that should work)

Comment: You correctly said _insertItems_ in problem description, but in code you use _insertItem_ (without s at the end) see documentation here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#insertItems

Comment: thank you .. I did not notice the missing "s" at all. that is the reason why it was not working.

Comment: @Zlatomir I intentionally formatted code without creating additional variable to show how to fill QComboBox "in one line of code". Sure, final decision about code formatting is up to you.

Comment: @rutsky thank you for the edit suggestion, but i think it's clearer to separate the QStringList add items, from the QComboBox add items.

Answer (score 2):

don't pass the sting list as pointer

```
ui->QComboBox->insertItem(0, sequence_len);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//Text that you want to QStringList
QStringList list;
list << "a" << "b" << "c";

//Instance of model type to QStringList
QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel();
model->setStringList(list);

ui->QComboBox->setModel(model);
```

In this case, `QStringList list` can be your list in `sequence_len`.